# Unable to mock ref object[] using MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mocking, moq

I am trying to mock a method call using MOQ. Method takes one string, two object ref array parameters.

Method Definition:

```
bool method1(string string1, ref object[] objectArray, ref object[] objectArray);
```

MOQ Setup:

```
var sampleArray = new object[1] { "test" };

interfaceObject.Setup(m => m.method1(It.IsAny<string>(), ref sampleArray, ref sampleArray)).Returns(true);
```

When i try to mock ref object as a parameter its working and i am getting the required output.

But when i tried to mock ref array object as a parameter its not working and also its not throwing any error.

Can someone help me to understand the issue with mocking ref array object parameters.

Comment: "its not working" doesn't give us any indication as to what you observe. It would really help if you would provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is your problem that the `Setup` is not matched so that you get another return value (`false` is the default for loose mocks) or get an error saying that no setup exists (strict mocks)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/). It's really powerful unit-testing framework. They don't have any limitations for ref and out params. Not even speaking about the fact that you can fake more than just public virtual methods with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I struggled with a similar problem and found out that Moq had some limitations when setting up methods with ref and out parameters. I had to switch to RhinoMocks then.